# Since last update markdown rendering doesnt work

Tags: feature-request, bug, android-app

I'm using the android official app, and sine I have updated it two hours ago, the markdown of the questions/answers is not properly renderized (Well doesn't tenderize at all).

Comment: I'm guessing you're seeing the posts as black boxes, which would make this bug a duplicate. Please comment on my answer on the question linked and post your device's specifications, thanks!